# Excel datetime plot

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have a data set which is nothing more than series of datetimes.

Ex:

```
X-axis|         | Y-axis

11/10/2014 8:56 | 1

11/10/2014 9:01 | 1

11/10/2014 9:04 | 1

11/10/2014 9:15 | 1
```

I have 5 sets of datetimes and I want to plot this in a excel scatter graph over time (X - time). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want date to be the X axis and time the Y axis?

Comment: date and time in Y axis and just a tic in x axis to represent data

Comment: sorry @fixer123 I switched the axis. my bad :). I have edited the question

Comment: So the X axis is a datetime scale, all of the Y values will be in a horizontal line at a value of 1, and what you're trying to visualize is the intervals between the 1s?

Comment: I want X axis in one minute intervals and plot points only at above times in the data series

Comment: I'm still trying to wrap my head around the concept.  It looks like the dates are the same and the times span about 20 minutes.  So the X axis will be in 1 min increments.  At the increments where you have a data point, you want a marker at Y=1.  The graph will show the relative intervals between the markers?

Comment: If that's correct, it's a piece of cake.  Highlight your data and plot it as an XY graph.  The rest is formatting.  Set the X axis start, end, and interval (suppress labels if you want).  If you don't want the markers at the top of the chart, format the Y axis.  Have it go from 0 to 2 and the markers will be in the middle.

Comment: Times are stored as fractional parts of a day, so to enter an increment of 1 minute, enter the fraction 1/1440 (=minutes per day; enter the fraction to avoid rounding error).

Answer (score 0):

I would first make a new column (that could be hidden if needed), that has the following function in it:
`=(A2-INT(A2))*24*60`
Which gives the time in minutes (it will not exceed 24 hours). Then you can create the plot using minutes. You can also use `=(A2-INT(A2))*24` for hours or `=(A2-INT(A2))` to use days.

Comment: how can I substitute time in minutes with the actual time in graph?

Comment: You use the last formula `=(A2-INT(A2))` and format the x-axis as time in hours:minutes.